# How many n-digit lists of digits 0 through 9 are there such that the digits 1,2,3, and 9 all appear at least once?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many n-digit lists of digits 0 through 9 are there such that the digits 1, 2, 3, and 9 all appear at least once?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The number of lists with n digits 1,2,3 or 9 less than the total number of n digit lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), viz.

Total number of strings - strings with at least 1 desired digit missing + strings with at least 2 desired digits missing - strings with at least 3 desired digits missing + ......

$= 10^n - \binom41 9^n + \binom42 8^n - \binom43 7^n + .......$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^4 (-1)^k\binom{4}{k}(10-k)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

Use *inclusion/exclusion* principle:

- Include the total number of lists, which is $10^n$
- Exclude the number of lists without at least $\color\red1$ of these digits, which is $\binom{4}{\color\red1}\cdot(10-\color\red1)^n$
- Include the number of lists without at least $\color\red2$ of these digits, which is $\binom{4}{\color\red2}\cdot(10-\color\red2)^n$
- Exclude the number of lists without at least $\color\red3$ of these digits, which is $\binom{4}{\color\red3}\cdot(10-\color\red3)^n$
- Include the number of lists without at least $\color\red4$ of these digits, which is $\binom{4}{\color\red4}\cdot(10-\color\red4)^n$

Note that the first bullet can also be written as $\binom{4}{\color\red0}\cdot(10-\color\red0)^n$, hence the answer is: $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{4}(-1)^k\cdot\binom{4}{k}\cdot(10-k)^n$$